# How can I export audio recording files with bookmarks from Samsung Voice Recorder app?

Tags: samsung, audio, samsung-voice-recorder

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8+ phone. I use the Voice Recorder app a lot and I also add several bookmarks to each file. Now, my phone is out of storage space and I need to back up my old recorded files to a computer. Although I know how to find the **m4a files** in my phone storage, I cannot find the **corresponding bookmarks** for each file.

So, my question is:

- Where can I find these bookmarks in my phone storage? If it is embedded in m4a files, how can I see them on my Windows PC?
- If it is only seeable in the same app, does it mean that if I move the files to my computer, I can access the file and its bookmarks whenever I move a copy of it to the recorder app on my phone?

Comment: *adb backup -f voicerec.ab -apk com.sec.android.app.voicenote*

Comment: Based on a possibly related question [How does Samsung's Voice Recorder's Speech-to-text function store the text and sync it with the audio?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232485/44325), perhaps the bookmarks are also embedded inside the file (answering the 2nd point). Not sure how to see decoded them if they're stored as serialized Java blobs.